# Can Redgate SQL Backup Restore SQB to Older SQL Version

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to take a backup of a 1.2TB database on a SQL 2019 instance.
Then restore the Backup to a SQL 2014 instance.

I know SQL won't allow this via .bak or attaching. Also the size of the DB makes Script Generation unlikely.

Does anyone know if Redgate SQL Backup can do this? Or any other piece of software that's worth purchasing.

Comment: Doesn't look like it (at least not redgate) - https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/86211/restore-to-earlier-version#:~:text=The%20simple%20answer%20here%20is,which%20are%20Redgate's%20comparison%20tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### no. you can't use backup/restore to "downgrade", no matter what backup software you use.

Redgate SQL Backup & other commercially available SQL Server backup software all have one thing in common: they all use Microsoft's API (known as the Virtual Backup Device Interface, or VDI) to take consistent copies of the database.

Essentially, they stream data from VDI the same way data is streamed by the built-in `BACKUP DATABASE` command, but then each vendor puts their "special sauce" on the data and file format. You can think of it as 3rd party backups just offering post-processing for backups (and pre-processing on restore).

Some backup software does alternatively use the Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS)  to backup at the disk/file level. These storage-based snapshots can be very fast, but are similarly "outside" SQL Server.

Regardless of which method is being used, both back up data in a way that is tied to the Database Engine's major version number.

If you want to "downgrade" a database, export/import is the only way to go. You can use the import/export wizard, or SSIS, or a BAKPAC or any other ETL tool you might have at your disposal. Just not a backup.